# how to store grouped data into json in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark

I have a dataset which looks like (just a snapshot of few columns)

[image: data description]

I want to group my data by key. My key is

```
CONCAT(a.div_nbr,a.cust_nbr)
```

My ultimate goal is to convert the data into JSON, formated like this

```
k1[{v1,v2,....},{v1,v2,....}], k2[{v1,v2,....},{v1,v2,....}],....
```

e.g

```
248138339 [{ PRECIMA_ID:SCP 00248 0000138339, PROD_NBR:5553505, PROD_DESC:Shot and a Beer Battered Onion Rings (5553505 and 9285840) , PROD_BRND:Molly's Kitchen,PACK_SIZE:4/2.5 LB, QTY_UOM:CA } , 
        { PRECIMA_ID:SCP 00248 0000138339 , PROD_NBR:6659079 , PROD_DESC:Beef Chuck Short Rib Slices, PROD_BRND:Stockyards , PACK_SIZE:12 LBA , QTY_UOM:CA} ,{...,...,} ],
```

1384611034793[{},{},{}],....

I have created a dataframe (I am joining two tables basically to get some more fields)

```
joinstmt = sqlContext.sql(
          "SELECT a.precima_id , CONCAT(a.div_nbr,a.cust_nbr) as
                  key,a.prod_nbr , a.prod_desc,a.prod_brnd ,      a.pack_size , a.qty_uom , a.sales_opp , a.prc_guidance , a.pim_mrch_ctgry_desc , a.pim_mrch_ctgry_id , b.start_date,b.end_date
```

FROM scoop_dtl a join scoop_hdr b on (a.precima_id =b.precima_id)")

Now, in order to get the above result I need to group by the result based on key, I did the following

```
groupbydf = joinstmt.groupBy("key")
```

This resulted intp a grouped data and after reading I got to know that I cannot use it directly and I need to convert it back into dataframes to store it.

I am new to it, need some help inorder to convert it back into dataframes or I would appreciate if there are any other ways as well.

Answer (score 5):

If your joined dataframe looks like this:

```
gender  age
M   5
F   50
M   10
M   10
F   10
```

You can then use below code to get desired output

```
joinedDF.groupBy("gender") \ 
    .agg(collect_list("age").alias("ages")) \
    .write.json("jsonOutput.txt")
```

Output would look like below:

```
{"gender":"F","ages":[50,10]}
{"gender":"M","ages":[5,10,10]}
```

In case you have multiple columns like name, salary. You can add columns like below:

```
df.groupBy("gender")
    .agg(collect_list("age").alias("ages"),collect_list("name").alias("names"))
```

Your output would look like:

```
{"gender":"F","ages":[50,10],"names":["ankit","abhay"]}
{"gender":"M","ages":[5,10,10],"names":["snchit","mohit","rohit"]}
```

Comment: thank you -- per the op's question, how may we extend your solution to data with more fields? E.g. if joinedDF contains [{'gender': 'M', 'name': 'kelly', 'age': 20}, {'gender': M, 'name': 'bob', 'age': 41}], then on grouping by 'gender' we achieve: {'gender': 'M', 'names':['kelly', 'bob'], 'ages': [20, 41]}

Comment: Updated my answer. hope that helps.

Comment: But are the collected list items ordered ? e.g. age 50 corresponds to ankit and age 10 corresponds to abhay in your examples ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `GroupedData` directly. It has to be aggregated first. It could be partially covered by aggregation with built-in functions like `collect_list` but it is simply not possible to achieve desired output, with values used to represent keys, using `DataFrameWriter`.

In can try something like this instead:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
import json

def make_json(kvs):
  k, vs = kvs
  return json.dumps({k[0]: list(vs)})

(df.select(struct(*keys), values)
    .rdd
    .mapValues(Row.asDict)
    .groupByKey()
    .map(make_json))
```

and `saveAsTextFile`.

Comment: Question for clarification: what do the variables "kvs", "*keys", and "values" correspond to in the OP's example?