# Spark grouped Dataframe details

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I achieve keys of a grouped `spark-dataframe`?

And another question:

What does a `pyspark.sql.group.GroupedData` object include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I achieve keys of a grouped spark-dataframe?

Without aggregating data and collecting the result it is not possible. It would be easier to just:

```
df.select(grouping_columns).distinct()
```

> What does a pyspark.sql.group.GroupedData object include?

Just the execution plan:

- [How to serialize pyspark GroupedData object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38600908/9613318)
- [how to store grouped data into json in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35673339/9613318)